# MacBook Air -- Cursor gets stuck as arrow/finger

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, bug, cursor

When I am using my MacBook Air, my cursor sometimes gets stuck and remains as either the default pointer (black arrow), or as the link-clicking finger. I generally have to quit the application and go back to it in order to temporarily rectify this issue. Honestly, it gets really annoying, so *why is this happening* and *how can I fix it*?

Note: I am just using the default trackpad...

Comment: Which application does it happen in? Boot into safe mode and see if it happens.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii - Safari only. How do you boot it into safe mode and how does safe mode change the way it runs?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267668/terminal-login-hangs/269286#269286  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365790/websites-with-heavy-use-of-websockets-skyrocket-cpu-usage-in-safari/365793#365793 See these answers for safe mode. It disables third party extensions. And since it is Safari,  restarting Safari without any browser extensions  or later, clearing up cache, can help locate the problem. @monomeeth